# A question regarding waves and photoelectric effect

Tags: waves, electromagnetic-radiation, photoelectric-effect

I was reading my physics textbook and there was an example in it in which an electromagnetic wave whose electric component varied with time as $$E=a(1+\cos\omega t)\cos\omega_0t$$ was incident on a lithium surface and required to find was the maximum kinetic energy of the emitted electron. The solution to the problem was as follows
$$E=a\cos\omega_0t+a\cos\omega_0t\,\cos\omega t$$
$$E=a\cos\omega_0 t+a/2[\cos(\omega-\omega_0)t+\cos(\omega+\omega_0)t]$$
then the book said that since maximum frequency is of the last component so the maximum kinetic energy electron will be emitted due to this component then the formulas of photoelectric effect were applied. My main doubt is that isn't the resultant electric field the superposition of the three components and so the frequency used should be of the resultant electric field and not that of any component.Like in beats in sound waves the frequency of the sound is the average of the two component sound waves while the beat frequency is half of the difference of the two frequencies.

Answer (score 0):

The textbook wans to put an upper limit to the energy expected from such a field. Imagine, for example,that the frequencies sum happily corresponds to a resonant frequency of an atom. Such a signal may well excite the atom.